# List of recommended patches for specific Sitecore version

Tags: configuration, security

Is there an easy way to find a list of recommended patches for a specific Sitecore version/update? I can see that individual patches are recommended for a particular version but I can't find a a list of all recommended patches.

Comment: Are you referring to environment patching.  The patches that Sitecore provides as examples, are there to help it to fit into specific scenarios.  In other words, no size fits all.

Comment: It's a good idea in theory, but I think it would be too complex to maintain such a list - perhaps a wiki would work though so the effort is distributed.

Comment: @DylanYoung I was referring to support patches.

Comment: I don't think that such a list exists. In theory you could go through all 1500+ repositories on https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/ and check the corresponding release pages for the affected Sitecore versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters above have said, there isn't a definitive list of patches for a specific version.

Answer (score 1):

To find all security patches for a specific Sitecore version, you can refer to the *Security Bulletin* section on the *Knowledge Base* website:

1. Browse to https://support.sitecore.com/kb
2. Click on the [Security Bulletins](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_search&kb_knowledge_base=44035465db70dc109e54320a689619bf) tab to see the most recent security bulletins and learn steps to make your Sitecore installation more secure.
3. You'll see filters on the left side to select language, Sitecore product and Sitecore versions.
4. Selecting the Sitecore version will give you all the patches applicable for this version.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no definitive list of patches for a specific Sitecore version, the best approach to this is to contact [Sitecore Support](http://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk). By providing them your Sitecore version, they can easily pull out the list of recommended patches that you required.

I did a Sitecore upgrade from 7.2 to 8.1 and the 7.2 instance had several Sitecore patches. By contacting Sitecore Support, they told me which patch is still required on the Sitecore 8.1.